# Use app name in intent filter action name

Tags: android, xml, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, intentfilter

I'm trying to create a BroadcastReveiver with couple of intent filters in AndroidManifest.xml. I need to use app name as a part of action name. For example:

```
<receiver android:name=".SomeBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="<app_name>.SOME_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I'm pretty sure it's not possible to do this but I hope there is some another way to do something like this?

I can register receiver in Application class but then it won't keep listening when app process is not not active. Is there any way to listen these actions as long as app is installed?

Comment: Hi, is there any problem with using a string literal for that? like for example "com.example.Appname"

Comment: several products are using same manifest file and while one needs to listen "com.example.App1.ACTION" other needs to listen "com.example.App2.ACTION". Looks like the only solution is overriding manifest file for each app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that "app name" is what Android developers refer to as the application ID (or the older "package name" term), use [manifest placeholders](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-Placeholder-support):

```
<action android:name="${applicationId}.SOME_ACTION" />
```

Comment: I actually meant app name but package name sounds like a much better solution. It worked, thanks!